# Drive Traffic to New Href Link when A Tag is Clicked

Tags: javascript, html, url, hyperlink, addeventlistener

I am working to pull the entire URL from the inbound traffic source of a page and extract a single query string value from it, and then use this value as part of a new URL.

The new URL will be used to send traffic to another page when it is clicked.

My code below I checked does go into the `fnView` function but I can't get the new url to be navigated to when the `a` tag is clicked.

**JavaScript**

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', pEvents);

function pEvents() {

  function fnView() {

    var queryString = window.location.search;
    var utm_content;

    if (queryString !== null) {
      utm_content = queryString.match(/utm_content=([^&]+)/)[1];
      var itemId = utm_content.toString();

      snaptr('track', 'VIEW_CONTENT', {
        'item_ids': itemId
      });
    } else {
      snaptr('track', 'VIEW_CONTENT');
    }
    document.getElementById('link').href = "https://www.sitedomain.com/m-pr.cfm?m=91020&u=2346350&p=" + itemId;
  };

  document.getElementById('link').addEventListener('click', fnView);

};
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="link" href="#">Click me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing the click after setting the href value. Just add this line:

```html
document.getElementById('link').click();
```